# Universal 'move' Method

Tags: iphone, methods, cocos2d-iphone, move, universal

I made a 'move' method for my enemy to move. The thing is that I have multiple different types of enemies, so I want them all to move relatively the same way. The only difference is the CCSpriteBatchNode, meaning the graphics are different. Is there a way to have the same move method, except modified a bit for each enemy type? Or is the only solution to copy and paste the method to each class and modify it there?

Comment: Do you want to show us the code you have now?

Comment: Yeah sure. It's just a basic move method.

Comment: Hold on let me get a link to it, it's too big to post

Comment: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your enemies should be a subclass of an "Enemy" base class. Implement the "move" function once, in the parent class, and then all the enemy subclasses will move the same way.

Comment: Yes ie ZombieEnemy : Enemy. So you're saying in the Enemy.h...what do I do?

Comment: Implement `-(void)move` in `Enemy` and not in `ZombieEnemy`. Then call `[myZombie move]` and the call will bubble up to the superclass and call the move method from Enemy. Then google "object orientation polymorphism".

Comment: Ok, what do I do about switching the CCSpriteBatchNode? Since move is now a general call, where do I init. the specific graphics for that enemy?

Comment: In your init, you'll do `self = [super init]` and then do whatever your subclass-specific initialization calls for. Any class you implement in the subclass doesn't bubble up to the superclass, so things specific to zombies get implemented in `ZombieEnemy`.

Comment: Ok, so what do I do in my original Enemy class to show that it's not a specific CCSpriteBatchNode yet? I still need one to set up the rest of the method. The code snippet is posted above in the comments. The thing I don't understand is, setting up the movement requires a CCSpriteBatchNode...what do I do in place of a specific one?

Comment: Your superclass should have iVars (and possibly properties) for everything it needs in its methods. The difference among the child classes is, those get populated with different things. Your move method doesn't need the CONTENTS of the sprite, just a handle to its CONTAINER.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Yes I have iVars and @properties etc. I also understand about your container for the contents solution, but I think I would understand more with an example. Should I import all of the necessary batchNodes?

Comment: I think you should step back and play a little with Objective-C inheritance. This is very basic OO stuff I'm walking you through, and if you just mess with it a little it'll all come clear.

Comment: I know, and thanks for your advice. I'm missing things, and I'm not sure what and how. What should I look at to understand this? I'll look at OO 'polymorphism', because I'm not quite sure what that is.

Comment: Just go get your hands dirty in the code. I know you don't understand everything yet, but you won't until you go play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an object oriented approach you can do this with inheritance and virtual functions. I guess objective C support this kind of programming.

Comment: _Virtual inheritance is not relevant in Objective-C, since inheritance cannot be multiple and has none of the associated problems._

Comment: Ok for multiple inheritance, but this is not your case. You just have a `move` function (which seems to be virtual automatically in Obj-C). Then you should be able to derive classes from your main class to create the different sprites. Those would also have (or not if not necessary) a `move` function in each sub-classes, that will be called when you use a main class object type which holds a derived class object. Then you always call `move` on your basic enemy class and depending on what instantiation you've done, the right move will be called (or the base class if sub-class don't have move)

Comment: Sorry...I'm not exactly following what you're saying

Comment: Take class A, and class B and C derived from A. You implement a virtual function in A called move. You can then override move in B with a new implementation (eventually calling the one of A) and don't write move for C. If you make a object `A a = new B();` you can call `a.move()` and it will execute the code you've written in B class. If you do the same with C, it will call the function of A since C don't implement this function. As I said I'm no Obj-C programmer, but I'm pretty confident you can do that as well.

Comment: Ok B+C = derived from A. In B you make an object 'a' and call a.move. What is new B? Sorry if I'm not making sense here.

Comment: Classes : A, B, C. A->B; A->C. If you create an object a of class A, you can store either real A object, or B object, or C object in it; but when you call a function of a, it's the function of the real object which is called.

Comment: So there's an a object from class A. what do you mean stored as real A object? I understand the rest